# command not found in bash-3.2$

Tags: linux, bash

I tried running a script file using bash but it showed an error

bash-3.2$ example.sh : command not found

I also tried 
ls -l example.sh

I found that it was not executable, so I used
 sudo chmod 777 example.sh

I again tried running it but same error was coming. I double checked that I am in the same folder as the file using ls. But still I am not able to execute the script file.

I finally tried making a dummy script file and running it , and found the same error

I think there is some problem with BASH. Can some one help me with what is the problem?

I am working on redhat, bash was already installed in my system

Since I am newbie on linux any help would be appreciated

Comment: Without a program, there is nothing we can do to help you. If the problem is not with the program but with the environment (linux, bash version, ...), you may have to ask at a different site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bash search for commands in your `$PATH`. Apparently the current directory, `.`, is not in your `$PATH`. (This is a good thing; having `.` in your `$PATH` is insecure.)

You'll need to specify a directory name. Just type:

```
./example.sh
```

Incidentally, doing:

```
sudo chmod 777 example.sh
```

is two kinds of overkill. First, you don't need to use `sudo`; use `sudo` *only* when you actually need to. Presumably your personal account owns the file, so you can just use `chmod` directly.

Second, `777` is *way* too permissive. It allows anyone on the system to read, execute, or *modify* `example.sh`. (If you're the only person on the system it may not matter much, but it's still a bad habit.)  Typically you should use `755` for directories and for files that need to be executable, and `644` for files that don't need to be executable.

Or just use

```
chmod +x example.sh
```

to set execute permission (your umask will prevent that from setting the permissions too loosely).

Comment: Thanks.. I was not aware of how the path system exactly works :)

Answer (score 3):

`.` (the current directory) is probably not on your path.  Try `./example.sh` or `bash example.sh`.  You could also add `.` to your `PATH` environment variable, but that's generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

Your bash PATH probably doesn't include `.`, try running it by typing:

```
./example.sh
```

When you type a command, your shell searches your path to try to find the command, if the current directory (e.g. `.`) isn't part of the path, the script that you are trying to run won't be found. You'd have to explicitly give it the path to where this command is. And since it's in your current directory, you can just add `./` in front of the command.

Answer (score 0):

first confirm the bash path 
to check the path of bash use:

```
 which bash
```

if you get "/bin/bash"
then add

```
#!/bin/bash 
...
...
```

or whatever is the path on first line of your bash script